# java wrapper around log4j logger and java.util.logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, thread-safety, java.util.logging

I am writing a library. The library can be used by applications that use log4j loggers and java.util.logging loggers.

So, I wrote a quick wrapper class, that encapsulates both loggers. I allow the application to set one or both loggers. And in my library I use the encapsulated class to print to either logger.

My question is, since many threads can simultaneously be using the same instance of the wrapper class to log messages using the class' methods (for example: fatal() below), what steps should be taken to make these methods thread safe?

```
public class MultiLogger {
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger _log4jLogger = null;
    private static java.util.logging.Logger _javaUtilLogger = null;

    private MultiLogger () {
    }

    // log4j FATAL, log util SEVERE
    public void fatal (Object message) {
        if (_log4jLogger != null) {
            _log4jLogger.log("", Level.FATAL, message, null);
        }

        if (_javaUtilLogger != null) {
            _javaUtilLogger.severe((String) message);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Any other comments appreciated too.

Comment: You should check out slf4j before you proceed with this library. It wraps all the major logging libraries and is very high quality.

Comment: that looks really good, but I cannot use any external libraries in my library

Comment: Uhm, how external is external? Isn't log4j an external library then? Where does this aversion against "external" libraries come from?

Comment: Good lord, how many logging libraries and wrappers does it take?  Personally, I think this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment:

> You should check out slf4j before you proceed with this library. It wraps all the major logging libraries and is very high quality.

But I presume that your wrapper class will be used in the same manner as the loggers that it wraps. In that case, the wrapped classes should handle the synchronization for you.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: slf4j, as per comment on question.

Option 2: cxf.apache.org has such a device in it. We use it instead of slf4j because slf4j lacks internationalization support. You are welcome to grab the code.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you're just using log4j and util Loggers as shown above, I don't think you'll run into any sync problems.